Issue with Storybook and Next.js 12
I just installed Storybook for my Next.js project using npx storybook@latest init following the official documentation. However, when I try to run Storybook, I encounter the following error:
Cannot find module 'next/dist/client/components/navigation'


Environment
Next.js version: 12.3.1 |
Storybook version: 8.3.5 |
Node version: 18
